# AWS Amplify Graph API sets incorrect default time for the "createdAt" field

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify

I've created a small aws-amplify/vue.js based app that contains a graph api. My model object automatically added two fields: createdAt and updatedAt, which are auto-populated when new models are created.

All works well except that the time that is recorded is two hours ahead of my local time. I'm based in Melbourne Australia and my S3 instance that is generated by aws-amplify is in the same timezone (as well as the generated DynamoDB & Lambda function).

Any idea how I can get the time to be correct?

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe time-zones are messing things up? Can you check the UTC time?

Comment: @pelocho I'm a tool. UTC checked out. I just had to ensure I was displaying it correctly. Thanks.